# How can I reorder RecyclerView from firebase permanently using ItemTouchHelper?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a firebase project. I used Itemtouchhelper to drag and reorder the recyclerview from firebase database but it resets to what it was if I enter another activity and comeback or restart the app. Is there a way to make the change to recyclerview order permanent?

---

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new 
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.START | 
 ItemTouchHelper.END, 0) {
 @Override
 public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
 viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();

Collections.swap(List, fromPosition, toPosition);

adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
return false;
 }

 @Override
 public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

 }};
```

---

```
 private void loadList() {
 List = new ArrayList<>();
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("List");
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    List.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot ss: snapshot.getChildren()){
        if(ss.child("moreList").child(ID).exists()){
            ListModel model = ss.getValue(ListModel.class);
            List.add(model);
        }
    }
    adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), List);
    RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(RecyclerView);

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

}
```

});

Comment: This is the exact same question you asked earlier today, which was closed for being off-topic.  Instead of just copying and pasting what didn't work last time, try making improvements to the question as suggested in the details left on that original question.

Comment: Sorry. I will make improvements to the question.